# How many lookup columns we can create per list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

How many look up columns we can create per list in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) the maximum number of lookup columns for a list in SharePoint 2013 is 96.

Comment: Same. To check it switch version in top of the article ("Other versions" dropdown).

Comment: but here mentioned list view lookup threshold 8.

Comment: It means that you can have maximum 8 lookup columns in a view but column not necessary should be included in any view.